# @RestController not working with spring-data-jpa starters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to create a simple Spring Boot project which uses spring data jpa for DB interactions.

Application Class:

```
package org.railway.fms.documentmgmt;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.railway.fms.documentmgmt.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages= {"org.railway.fms.documentmgmt.entities"})
public class FMSApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FMSApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller Class:

```
package org.railway.fms.documentmgmt;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class NatureOfDocumentRestService {

    @GetMapping("/document/nature")
    public String getNatureOfDocuments() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'document-mgmt'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation ("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

application.properties

```
# Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5444/db?currentSchema=fms
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The problem I am facing is when not using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency in my build.gradle file, I am able to successfully hit my controller from the browser.

But when I am using the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` then the controller is not loaded in spring context and I am unable to hit the controller from  my browser.

How do I use spring-data-jpa in my spring boot project containing exposed web sevices, please help !

Note : there is no error in logs, application starts successfully.

logs:

```
2019-06-10 09:52:11.348  INFO 15540 --- [           main] o.r.fms.documentmgmt.FMSApplication      : Starting FMSApplication on abcd with PID 15540 (C:\Users\furquan.ahmed\Workspaces\fmsWorkspace\document-mgmt\bin\main started by furquan.ahmed in C:\Users\furquan.ahmed\Workspaces\fmsWorkspace\document-mgmt)
2019-06-10 09:52:11.354  INFO 15540 --- [           main] o.r.fms.documentmgmt.FMSApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-10 09:52:12.200  INFO 15540 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-06-10 09:52:12.228  INFO 15540 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-06-10 09:52:13.083  INFO 15540 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5149c32d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-06-10 09:52:14.106  INFO 15540 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-06-10 09:52:14.161  INFO 15540 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-06-10 09:52:14.162  INFO 15540 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-06-10 09:52:14.402  INFO 15540 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-06-10 09:52:14.402  INFO 15540 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2968 ms
2019-06-10 09:52:14.714  INFO 15540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-06-10 09:52:18.002  INFO 15540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-06-10 09:52:18.099  INFO 15540 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-06-10 09:52:18.267  INFO 15540 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.9.Final}
2019-06-10 09:52:18.268  INFO 15540 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-06-10 09:52:18.494  INFO 15540 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-06-10 09:52:19.060  INFO 15540 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: Please post `application.properties` file and the logs.

Comment: there are no errors in log, I have added logs and properties file

Comment: You mean as 'HAL' ?

Comment: sorry , I didn't understand !

Answer (score 0):

If there's no direct need to explicitly state the `basePackages` for `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan`, I would suggest letting Spring find out the locations by means of auto-configuration, as all your classes are located in `org.railway.fms.documentmgmt`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class FMSApplication { ... }
```

Otherwise, try adding a `@ComponentScan` to state the location of Spring components:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.railway.fms.documentmgmt.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages= "org.railway.fms.documentmgmt.entities")
@ComponentScan(basePackages= "org.railway.fms.documentmgmt")
public class FMSApplication { ... }
```

Furthermore, if you do need to state the base package location, there's also the option to use [`basePackageClasses`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#basePackageClasses--) instead of `basePackages`, which is a type-safe alternative.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help

Comment: There is no need in explicit ComponentScan as well since `@SpringBootApplication` includes `@ComponentScan` with same default package (where FMSApplication class is located)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

> The problem I am facing is when not using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in my build.gradle file, I am able to successfully hit my controller from the browser.
>   But when I am using the org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa then the controller is not loaded in spring context and I am unable to hit the controller from my browser.

I think when you are adding `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` you may be forgetting to add db config in in `application.properties` 
If I'm correct then add below properties in `application.properties` file and replace the values with specific to you db

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

in case you have already added these properties. Could you please provide logs and stack trace to see what errors are you getting.

Comment: I have these properties in my application.properties and the application successfully connects to database, but controller class is not loaded into spring context.

Comment: I don't see any error. Moreover there is nothing like server started. I'm doubting you have put whole log or not. Can you create a minimum project and upload to github and share Repo URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define below properties in your application.properties file.

```
server.servlet.context-path
spring.data.rest.base-path
```

Now access your controller mappings using the context-path and the rest repository mappings using rest.base-path.